# Gray Level Co occurrence Matrix of image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image, glcm

- I am working on obtaining `Gray Level Co-occurrence Matrix` of an image and also to calculate `Homogeneity`, `Correlation`, `Entropy` and `Kurtosis` of this matrix using **Python**.
- I imported `greycomatrix` and `greycoprops` from [skimage](https://scikit-image.org) and obtained `GLCM` image.

> There were built in functions to get Homogeneity and Correlation but didnt get any for  Entropy and Kurtosis.

- Is there any built in or custom codes to get `Entropy` and `kurtosis` so that I can modify from my Python code, given below:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import greycomatrix, greycoprops
from skimage import io, color, img_as_ubyte

img = io.imread('ff.jpg')

gray = color.rgb2gray(img)
image = img_as_ubyte(gray)
io.imshow(image)

bins = np.array([0, 16, 32, 48, 64, 80, 96, 112, 128, 144, 160, 176, 192, 208, 224, 240, 255]) #16-bit
inds = np.digitize(image, bins)

max_value = inds.max()+1
matrix_coocurrence = greycomatrix(inds, [1], [0, np.pi/4, np.pi/2, 3*np.pi/4], levels=max_value, normed=False, symmetric=False)

# GLCM properties
def contrast_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    contrast = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'contrast')
    return "Contrast = ", contrast

def dissimilarity_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    dissimilarity = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'dissimilarity')    
    return "Dissimilarity = ", dissimilarity

def homogeneity_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    homogeneity = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'homogeneity')
    return "Homogeneity = ", homogeneity

def energy_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    energy = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'energy')
    return "Energy = ", energy

def correlation_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    correlation = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'correlation')
    return "Correlation = ", correlation


def entropy_feature(matrix_coocurrence):
    entropy = greycoprops(matrix_coocurrence, 'entropy')
    return "Entropy = ", entropy

print(contrast_feature(matrix_coocurrence))
print(dissimilarity_feature(matrix_coocurrence))
print(homogeneity_feature(matrix_coocurrence))
print(energy_feature(matrix_coocurrence))
print(correlation_feature(matrix_coocurrence))
```

Comment: `skimage.filters.rank` has an entropy function. As for the other metrics there are propably packages somewhere that have those too. Though it is probably a lot faster and cleaner to implement those functions yourself, it is like 1 line each.